# Setting either a session variable or form variable in CF

Tags: coldfusion

I have a JavaScript and jquery fee calculator that uses functions to figure out the fee total and then they display as so

```
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

Is it possible to set that totalPrice to a coldfusion session variable or form variable so I can use that amount on a few other pages... Like there checkout page and there payment page?

Any help is greatly appreciated I just didn't know if this is even possible?

```
function calculateTotal()
{

    var titleFees = initialRegFee();
    titleFees += specialFee;


    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}
```

Example of how the div display works
http://jsfiddle.net/hwcu7e05/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a variable from JavaScript (browser) to ColdFusion session or form scope, simply post the value(s) using a HTML form post, or an Ajax post (e.g. using jQuery) to a cfm page, and you will see the variable in the `Form` scope.  Then you are free to set it to a `Session` scope.

Comment: So its something like this?`<cfparam name="form.submitted" default="#session.checkout.vehicle.fees#"><cfif form.submitted><div id="totalPrice"></div></cfif><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />`

Comment: Did you download the sample files?  http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Installing_Sample_Files/ Follow the tutorial and you will learn it.